# How to rollback operation npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed one dependency using npm. After that server is not run. How to rollback this operation(npm install)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `npm remove <package>` to remove the package again. I don't think there is an explicit `rollback`.

Comment: remove you just remove the package from the `package.json`, to really delete this dependency: delete the folder `node_modules` and run `npm install` again

Comment: I think `remove` is an alias for `uninstall`. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/uninstall

Comment: Problem is that after remove I have an error still, that was experienced after install npm

Comment: You could try removing the `node_modules` directory as @MarceloFilho suggests.

Comment: I can not, because it is required

Answer (score 1):

If you used the npm install command,

```
npm install package_name
```

Then you can use the following command to uninstall the package

```
npm uninstall package_name
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are tracking your files using a Version Control System, you simply need to discard the changes in the `package.json` file, save all your files, then run `npm install`